# Joining SHP with XLS sheet using Excel

Tags: arcmap, fields-attributes, attribute-joins, excel, concatenation

I am trying to join SHP by field CONCATENATE with my XLS sheet.
SHP attributes looks like this:

| ID | NAME | CONCATENATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 122 | 765 | 122765 |
| 345/1 | 765 | 345/1765 |
| 987/3 | 345 | 987/3345 |

Because of those slashes in ID fields, I choose to TEXT type for field CONCATENATE.

When I open DBF file (from that shp) in Excel, I add a field MATH, where I will calculate, then save it as XLS.

To problem is that when I try to join my SHP by field CONCATENATE with XLS sheet by field CONCATENATE ArcMap can't offer it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Dont edit shapefile dbf in excel, you can easly corrupt it. Add the shapefile to ArcMap and do the processing using Field Calculator. For example if you need to remove the /, you can do it using field calculator. Can you add a screenshot showing the shapefile attribute table and your xls file as they appear in ArcMap?

Comment: well, I need to take that DBF and save it like a XLS and then edit it, because that excel will use people who are not familiar with GIS at all and when they are done with calculating, I will do the rest.....yes tomorrow at work I will show picture....but basically dropdown menu doesn´t show field CONCATENATE from XLS sheet...other fields shows

Comment: Ok then I dont understand what you are trying to do. You can export to xls from arcmap using https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/conversion-toolbox/table-to-excel.htm. You could build a model, and show them how to execute a model

Comment: they don´t have a access to ArcMap - lawyer department....they just calculate what share of rental agreements people have and then I work with those numbers.......tommorow I try table to excel if it will work and if that field wil show up